# Differences between Mathematica versions 11 and 12 regarding ODE solution

Tags: differential-equations

Solving the ODE

$$
(\lambda +y(x)) y''(x)-y'(x)^2-1=0
$$

with Version 11 I got the solution

```
yx = 1/2 (Exp[-Exp[C[1]] (C[2] + x) - 2 C[1]] + Exp[Exp[C[1]] (C[2] + x)] - 2 lambda)
```

which is the same given by WolframAlpha while in Version 12 for the same ODE I got the solution

```
yx = -lambda - Tanh[E^C[1] (x + C[2])]^2/Sqrt[-E^(2 C[1]) Sech[E^C[1] (x + C[2])]^2 Tanh[E^C[1] (x + C[2])]^2]
```

This last result isn't even real: see the radical at the denominator after FullSimplify . My question is regarding how to ask the solver in Version 12 to obtain the Version 11 answer. Thanks.

Comment: can you explain more why you think the solution is not real? What is the issue with the denominator.? It is Tanh^2 -1 . Why is this a problem? Also, the solutions given do satisfy the ODE just fine.

Comment: When solving for the boundary conditions $y(0) = y(2) = 0$ we have to solve for **C[1], C[2]** the equations $$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 -\frac{\tanh ^2\left(e^{c_1} c_2\right)}{\sqrt{-e^{2 c_1} \tanh ^2\left(e^{c_1} c_2\right) \text{sech}^2\left(e^{c_1}
   c_2\right)}}-\lambda =0 \\
 -\frac{\tanh ^2\left(e^{c_1} (c_2+2)\right)}{\sqrt{-e^{2 c_1} \tanh ^2\left(e^{c_1} (c_2+2)\right) \text{sech}^2\left(e^{c_1}
   (c_2+2)\right)}}-\lambda =0 \\
\end{array}
\right) $$ which gives complex solutions when the solutions according to V 11 should be real.

Comment: Here $\lambda \approx 1.62$

Comment: There is no solution with these boundary conditions. What did version 11 give as solution using same boundary conditions? But V 12.1.1 solution does satisfy the ODE,. I checked. It will be useful to put all these information in your question so one can spot it more easily.

Comment: With Version 11 I got the solution $c_1 = 0.483741, c_2 = -1.29821$ for $\lambda = 1.62174$.

Comment: Which releases of Version 11 and Version 12 did you use to obtain the two solutions?  I obtain the same answers with 11.3.0 and 12.1.1, and the common answer is not the same as either in the question.  Please clarify.  Also, you should not assume that `C[1]` is the same for the two expressions in the question or that it is a real quantity.

Comment: As you can verify both solutions obey the ODE but the second obtained from version V 12.0.0 can't be used to obtain the $y(x)$ obeying the boundary conditions $y(0)=y(2)=0$ for $\lambda = 1.62174$ This is a catenary line problem that can be solved using the V 11.0.0 or V 10.0.0 solution. In time: both solutions obey the ODE.